# How can I shorten my code for all these checkboxes

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently using Python Flask and have about 60 checkboxes on my website.
I've already written working code for it but it takes up a lot of space.
Is there an easier and shorter way to write this code?
I would like to print an output for each selected checkbox.

```py
@app.route("/checkbox", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def checkbox_value():
    checkbox_data_1 = ""  
    checkbox_title_1 = ""  
    checkbox_data_2 = ""
    checkbox_title_2 = "" 
    checkbox_data_3 = ""  
    checkbox_title_3 = ""  
    checkbox_data_4 = ""
    checkbox_title_4 = ""  
    checkbox_data_5 = ""  
    checkbox_title_5 = ""  
    checkbox_data_6 = ""
    checkbox_title_6 = ""   
    if request.method == 'POST':   
        if request.form.get("checkbox1"):
            checkbox_data_1 = some_data
            checkbox_title_1 = some_other_data
        if request.form.get("checkbox2"):
            checkbox_data_2 = some_data
            checkbox_title_2 = some_other_data
        if request.form.get("checkbox3"):
            checkbox_data_3 = some_data
            checkbox_title_3 = some_other_data
        if request.form.get("checkbox4"):
            checkbox_data_4 = some_data
            checkbox_title_4 = some_other_data
        if request.form.get("checkbox5"):
            checkbox_data_5 = some_data
            checkbox_title_5 = some_other_data
        if request.form.get("checkbox6"):
            checkbox_data_6 = some_data
            checkbox_title_6 = some_other_data
    
    return render_template('index.html', checkbox_data_1=checkbox_data_1, checkbox_title_1=checkbox_title_1,
                           checkbox_data_2=checkbox_data_2, checkbox_title_2=checkbox_title_2,
                           checkbox_data_3=checkbox_data_3, checkbox_title_3=checkbox_title_3,
                           checkbox_data_4=checkbox_data_4, checkbox_title_4=checkbox_title_4,
                           checkbox_data_5=checkbox_data_5, checkbox_title_5=checkbox_title_5,
                           checkbox_data_6=checkbox_data_6, checkbox_title_6=checkbox_title_6)
```

Edit.

Here is my current attempt, but I always get the error message **jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'checkboxes' is undefinded**

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    checkboxes = { f"{i}": {"data": "", "title": ""} for i in range(1, 61) }
    my_numbers = []
    my_column = []
    if request.method == 'POST'
        inpt = request.form['inpt']
        inpt2 = request.form['inpt2']
        output = False
  
    
        for text in df['A']:
            if text == inpt:
                give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
                give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis = 1)
                output = True
        
        if output == True:

            for column in give_text:
                column_edit = give_text[column]
                my_columns.append(column)
                column_edit = float(column_edit) * float(inpt2)
            
                if '(m)' in column:
                    column_edit = column_edit + 'meter'
                    my_numbers.append(column_edit)
                elif 'cm' in column:
                    column_edit= column_edit + 'centimeter'
                    my_numbers.append(column_edit)

              for i in range(1, 61):
                 if request.form.get(f"checkbox{i}"):
                    checkboxes[f"{i}"]["data"] = my_numbers[f"{i}"]
                    checkboxes[f"{i}"]["title"] = my_column[f"{i}"]



              return render_template('index.html',checkboxes=checkboxes, my_numbers_0 = 
                my_numbers[0], my_column_0 =
                my_column[0], 
                my_numbers_1 = my_numbers[1], my_column_1 =my_column[1], 
                my_numbers_2 = my_numbers[2], my_column_2 = my_column[2], 
                my_numbers_3 = my_numbers[3], my_column_3 = my_column[3], 
                my_numbers_4 = my_numbers[4], my_column_4 = my_column[4], 
                my_numbers_5 = my_numbers[5], my_column_5 = my_column[5],inpt = inpt)
      else:
           return render_template('index.html', content = 'No Result')
```

Comment: You could write a loop and replace the many if statements with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try dictionary and return list/dict (change a bit your html), adapt this code to your needs:

```py
@app.route("/checkbox", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def checkbox_value():
    checkboxes = {"checkbox1": ("", ""), "checkbox2": ("", ""), }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for checkbox in checkboxes:
            if request.form.get(checkbox):
                checkboxes[checkbox][0] = some_data
                checkboxes[checkbox][1] = some_other_data
    return render_template('index.html', checkboxes=checkboxes.values())
```

In **Python 3.8+**:

```py
@app.route("/checkbox", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def checkbox_value():
    checkboxes = {"checkbox1": (checkbox_data_1:="", checkbox_title_1:=""), "checkbox2": (checkbox_data_2:="", checkbox_title_2:=""), }
    if request.method == 'POST':
       for checkbox in checkboxes:
            if request.form.get(checkbox):
                checkboxes[checkbox][0] = some_data
                checkboxes[checkbox][1] = some_other_data

    return render_template('index.html', checkboxes_tuples=checkboxes.values())
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. Which checkbox names do I have to call in my template? **checkboxes_tuples**?  Or how can I print my "data" and my "title" separately

Comment: You can iterate over the list in your template (or create another template only for checkboxes), i.e.: `{% for checkbox in checkbox_tuples %} {{ checkbox[0] }} {% endfor %}` but i don't know, if it's the case.

Comment: When I try this I always get this error: **TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment**. in the line `checkboxes [checkbox] [0] = some_data`.

Comment: Try to use list instead of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

following the same idea as the other answer, if you have 60 checkboxes and really need to know its number (instead of just looping on a list), you could do something like this:

```
@app.route("/checkbox", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def checkbox_value():
    checkboxes = { f"{i}": {"data": "", "title": ""} for i in range(1, 61) }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in range(1, 61):
            if request.form.get(f"checkbox{i}"):
                checkboxes[f"{i}"]["data"] = some_data
                checkboxes[f"{i}"]["title"] = some_other_data
    
    return render_template('index.html', checkboxes=checkboxes)
```

then in your template, you can just call any checkbox like `{{ checkboxes["1"]["data"] }}` or `{{ checkboxes["1"]["title"] }}`

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. When I use your method I always get the error **jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'checkbox' is undefinded.** In the line **{{ checkbox["1"]["data"] }}**
I've also tried "checkboxes" instead of "checkbox", but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi ,yeah sorry it should have been `checkboxes` instead of `checkbox`, my bad! but with `checkboxes` jinja2 should work... try `print(checkboxes)` just before you render the template, the only reason why it could throw that error is because it equals `None`.

Comment: I've tried your code again, but it didn't work. I edited my question. I've posted my current code there, where I've included your suggestion. Maybe you will see a mistake somewhere.

Comment: why are u not sending the checkboxes when it is a GET request?
The standard is to render the view on a get request, cause that's what the browser will do when it calls that route. If u are rendering these checkboxes on your view, you have to send them as args `return render_template('index.html', checkboxes=checkboxes`. 
Then, once the user has interacted with these checkboxes, and u wanna save the results, that's when u send a post request (assuming they're part of a form element), and do whatever you need to do with that information.
What are u trying to achieve with this view?